# Git & Netbeans -> Resetting a repo after it appears to have been corrupted

Tags: git, netbeans

I am not very nuanced when it comes to GIT, despite my attempts in learning it, so pardon my asking what may be a simple question.

I have been developing an autodidactic program in Java (a secondary language to me), and using Git to store commits. I have also been pushing to a TFS server, which uses Git.

Now, apparently the repo has corrupted itself. I think it's a problem with Sharepoint Workspaces...but that's besides the point, as I now cannot commit my changes to either my local repository, nor to the upstream one.

Could someone kindly walk me through the steps to (hopefully) uncorrupt my repo, and allow me to commit again? Normally I'd just blow it away, and redownload the project...but I've made some changes to the code, and would like to know if I can somehow save those changes without resorting to some sort of a painful process (i.e. going file by file, and popping them in, or using a diff tool, etc.). Is there any way to just reinitialize the repo, then tell it to grap the local (uncommitted) files, and commit them?

Part of the fun is that this is in NetBeans, which has code guards, which makes modifying code a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details:

- What commands/actions do you use to store the commits and pull/push?
- What message error you receive when try to commit in your repository?
- Your previous commits are on the server?
- Can you use the git log command?

The command: `git log origin/master..HEAD`

can show your unpushed commits. You can do a diff and a patch with the modifications to apply in a new repo, with this command:

```
git diff origin/master..HEAD >> modifications_not_pushed.diff
```